Populating all rows in a specified column with values from an array C#
I'm working in C#. I have a table with a column called "Months" and I have an array, ["Jan", "Feb", "Mar"]. I want the table to look like this:
Months
-------
Jan
Feb
Mar

Is there an easy way to do this without looping through the months array and setting the value of each row individually?
All of the examples I've seen set values of a table horizontally, but I'd like to set them by column vertically.

Array, List, Enumerable.Range.... there are plenty of ways to create a list, but at runtime each item will probably still be set one at a time.

Why do you want to do it without looping?
